# Changing colour of text in a textblock via a trigger

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

Here is my Xaml

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <sampleData:MainWindow x:Key="DataSource"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="bobReferencer">                      
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" >
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasErrors}" Value="true">
                          //what goes in here?
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>                                            
    </DataTemplate>    
</Window.Resources>
```

Codebehind (the one xaml references)

```
public class bob
{

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
 }
```

Basically what i want to do is if the HasErrors is true then i want the Name to appear in Red via the trigger. But my xaml is not properly formed. Any suggestions on this?  I also looked into this link but didn't help much.
[How can I change the Foreground color of a TextBlock with a Trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914943/how-can-i-change-the-foreground-color-of-a-textblock-with-a-trigger)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there..

```
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasErrors}" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: basically the value should be red. but thats works :) thanks Gleng i'll approve this as a valid answer once i get the permit from admin

Comment: Also make sure your model class (Bob) implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and have the property raise the event in the setter so that the UI knows to update.

Comment: @Net Dev Well Spotted! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a setter inside the DataTrigger

```
 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
```